# array.map Differences between Client and Node Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, momentjs

I am using moment.js to transform the format of a date. When executing the following code, if it is executed from the client, the result is correct. But if I run the exact same code from the Node server, it doesn't work ... What could be happening?

```
     const data = [{id:1,date: "2021-06-21T00:00:00.000Z"},{id:2,date: "2021-06-22T00:00:00.000Z"},{id:3,date: "2021-06-23T00:00:00.000Z"}]
     const result = data.map( x => {
              x.date= moment(x.date).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
              return x
              });
    
      console.log(result)

    //Return from client (Chrome, Firefox):
    [{id:1,date: "21/06/2021"},{id:2,date: "22/06/2021"},{id:3,date: "23/06/2021"}]

    //Return from Node.js:
    [{id:1,date: "2021-06-21T00:00:00.000Z"},{id:2,date: "2021-06-22T00:00:00.000Z"},{id:3,date: "2021-06-23T00:00:00.000Z"}]
```

Comment: nothing wrong with your code. are you console.log(data) instead of console.log(result)?

Comment: nop. I don't understand what is wrong

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of Array.map is not different on server and client.

The real problem is that the server and the client handle time differently.

Usually, the server time is set based on UTC and the client follows the system time of the OS.

Search by UTC, timezone, offset, etc.

```
"new Date()" on the browser and on the server will give different results.

[browser]
result > Fri Jun 04 2021 09:37:57 GMT+0900

[server]
result > 2021-06-04T00:38:03.316Z
```

Comment: Hello. I understand what you explain, but it does not solve the problem. I have set the UTC option in the moment settings: moment (x.date) .utc (). Format ('DD / MM / YYYY'); The result is the same. It does not work.
Set the same time zone on the server side and the client side. The downside continues.
I can't think of solutions anymore.